# Can't log in with new email to Stack Overflow

Tags: support, login

I have changed my old email address to a new one. The problem is that I can't log in with the new email address. It shows email, or password incorrect, but I can still log in with the old email address.

I have tried it many times with the same password. Why can't I log in with the new email address?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/USER-ID (this link will also work without changing USER-ID to your own ID)and add the new email address for logging in and then you can use that new email for logging there. You can delete the old email if you don't want it.

Comment: No need to bother replacing USER-ID with your actual user id, it will work anyway.

Comment: When i tried that, SO wouldnt detect my account when logging in afterwards. The solution was to [log off and on again](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p85xwZ_OLX0)) ...

Comment: It's great that it worked for you @NilsLindemann, but when I faced the same issue around 2 years ago, what I did is mentioned in the answer, anyways thanks for your opinion :)

Comment: @Gourav That is not an opinion but a recapitulation of an occurrence.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Thank you :)