# Unexpected behaviour for link to my logins page

Tags: bug, login

Recently I received [a comment on my answer on a Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386691).

I had stated a link which was the solution of the question. The link was: https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/USER-ID
Which goes to a page that shows the email addresses used to login to Stack Overflow. Now the comment says that you don't need to change "USER-ID" to your ID, it will redirect to the logins page as usual, but when I experimented with the link, like I used this link in the URL Bar:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins

But this time it didn't go to the desired page, now I tried with: https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/AnYThiNGHeRE i.e., random text at the end, but to my surprise it redirected to my email addresses page

Is this the required behavior? But should we not let only user ID of a specific user logged in at that time at the end of the URL to go to the required page?

**NOTE**: You may first try out yourself how this unexpected behavior works.

Comment: Yes, this seems like a redirect bug https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/ will give you not found. https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/AnYThiNGHeRE gives you your login page. This should be fixed right?

Comment: Yes @weegee This doesn't seem the right behviour